# PowerBI | DAX | How to wrap commands within a Condition

Tags: powerbi, dax

On PowerBI, I have a "url" column.  I would like to wrap the following commands within an if condition. How can I achieve the following?

```
IF (SomeCondition, 
{
//list of commands to be executed if condition passes
VAR myurl = SUBSTITUTE(test[url],"+"," ")
VAR begining = LEN(myurl)-SEARCH("query=",myurl)-5
VAR right_string = RIGHT(myurl, begining)
VAR ending = IF(CONTAINSSTRING(right_string, "&type"), SEARCH("&type",right_string)-2, len(right_string))
VAR finalString = TRIM(LEFT(right_string,ending))
} , {
// List of commands to be executed if condition fails 
})

RETURN finalString
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define VAR before you use it

```
    Link = 
    //list of commands to be executed if condition passes
    VAR myurl = SUBSTITUTE(test[url],"+"," ")
    VAR begining = LEN(myurl)-SEARCH("query=",myurl)-5
    VAR right_string = RIGHT(myurl, begining)
    VAR ending = IF(CONTAINSSTRING(right_string, "&type"), 
   SEARCH("&type",right_string)-2, len(right_string))
   VAR finalString = TRIM(LEFT(right_string,ending))
   RETURN
   IF (SOMECONDITION,finalString ,BLANK())
```

Comment: I would like to know how to wrap multiple commands within an if condition. 
I don't want to run the SEARCH on the url, if the url doesn't contain specific term such as "search/" 
Following is the error that comes up when SEARCH is run on a url that doesn't contain the required string.  Also to run commands in a more memory efficient way .. 
The search Text provided to function 'SEARCH' could not be found in the given text.

Comment: I don't I understand what you try to do?. You want to use nested if's statements?
IF(A=TRUE(),A, 
 IF(B=TRUE(),B,C))

Maybe you can provide example of data and expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simplified situation:

```
Measure =
VAR A1 = [A1]
VAR A2 = [A2]
VAR B1 = [B1]
VAR B2 = [B2]
RETURN
    IF (
        [SomeCondition],
        A1 + A2,
        B1 + B2
    )
```

DAX variables are evaluated lazily so that if `SomeCondition` is true, then it should only refer back to `A1` and `A2` and ignore `B1` and `B2` entirely. If the condition fails, then `A1` and `A2` are not evaluated and shouldn't hurt performance.

Comment: You see A1 + A2 is just one command.  In its place, what if I were to process multiple commands such as the one in the question above?

Comment: You can put everything except the last step as variables.